Deconstructing a tuple when using sorted with lambda function on key
I work with frequencies (%) and entropy (bits). Those two realities are very similar and it's very easy to mix them up.
When I have tuples of frequency/entropy, I ALWAYS name the tuple members so my code is easier to understand.
I am struggling to find a solution for the function sorted(). Just check the code below:
import math

def entropy(probability: float) -> float:
    if probability == 0: return 0
    else: return -probability*math.log(probability)/math.log(2)

pairs = [(frequency/10, entropy(frequency/10)+entropy(1-frequency/10)) for frequency in range(11)]
print(pairs)
print(sorted(pairs, key=lambda f, e: -e * 1000 + f))

I would really love to be able to write the lambda function with two arguments f and e, but my Python keeps saying there is a syntax error there: No overloads for "sorted" match the provided arguments.
Is there a way to do this in Python or should I give into a @dataclass like this:
@dataclass
class Pair:
    frequency: float = 0.0
    uncertainty: float = 0.0


"I ALWAYS name the tuple members so my code is easier to understand." none of them are named

print(sorted(pairs, key=lambda tup: -tup[1] * 1000 + tup[0])) works. Again, we go back to your insistence on naming everything.

The key function needs to take a single argument, which is your tuple.  If you want want to name the components of the tuple, then don't use a lambda, but use an ordinary named function.  Then you can do frequency, uncertainty = arg and then use the names  in the expression for the key value.

If you don't like dataclasses, you can use collections.namedtuple.

In Python 2, you could write lambda (f, e): ..., in which case the tuple passed to the function would be automatically unpacked into f and e. The feature was removed in Python 3, however.

If you want to name both elements of your tuple, you can use a namedtuple instead of a conventional tuple.
from collections import namedtuple
import math

f_S = namedtuple("f_S", ["frequency", "entropy"])

def entropy(probability: float) -> float:
    if probability == 0: return 0
    else: return -probability*math.log(probability)/math.log(2)

pairs = [f_S(frequency/10, entropy(frequency/10)+entropy(1-frequency/10)) for frequency in range(11)]
print("pairs:", pairs)
print("sorted:", sorted(pairs, key=lambda fS: -fS.entropy * 1000 + fS.frequency))

Output:
pairs: [f_S(frequency=0.0, entropy=0.0), f_S(frequency=0.1, entropy=0.4689955935892812), f_S(frequency=0.2, entropy=0.7219280948873623), f_S(frequency=0.3, entropy=0.8812908992306927), f_S(frequency=0.4, entropy=0.9709505944546688), f_S(frequency=0.5, entropy=1.0), f_S(frequency=0.6, entropy=0.9709505944546688), f_S(frequency=0.7, entropy=0.8812908992306927), f_S(frequency=0.8, entropy=0.7219280948873623), f_S(frequency=0.9, entropy=0.46899559358928117), f_S(frequency=1.0, entropy=0.0)]
sorted: [f_S(frequency=0.5, entropy=1.0), f_S(frequency=0.4, entropy=0.9709505944546688), f_S(frequency=0.6, entropy=0.9709505944546688), f_S(frequency=0.3, entropy=0.8812908992306927), f_S(frequency=0.7, entropy=0.8812908992306927), f_S(frequency=0.2, entropy=0.7219280948873623), f_S(frequency=0.8, entropy=0.7219280948873623), f_S(frequency=0.1, entropy=0.4689955935892812), f_S(frequency=0.9, entropy=0.46899559358928117), f_S(frequency=0.0, entropy=0.0), f_S(frequency=1.0, entropy=0.0)]


Each element of the list pairs is a tuple and one of the element of the tuple is considered as f and another element is e. lambda doesn't work this way.
import math

def entropy(probability: float) -> float:
    if probability == 0: return 0
    else: return -probability*math.log(probability)/math.log(2)

pairs = [(frequency/10, entropy(frequency/10)+entropy(1-frequency/10)) for frequency in range(11)]

# Use x[0] instead of f and x[1] instead of e and create a list
res = [(-x[1] * 1000 + x[0]) for x in pairs ]

#Create a dct mapping res and pairs
dct = dict(list(zip(res, pairs)))

#Sort res
res = sorted(res)

#Get values of the dct as a list being keys in the sorting order of res 
result = [v for x in res for k,v in dct.items() if x == k]

print(result)


#Output:
[(0.5, 1.0), (0.4, 0.9709505944546688), (0.6, 0.9709505944546688), (0.3, 0.8812908992306927), (0.7, 0.8812908992306927), (0.2, 0.7219280948873623), (0.8, 0.7219280948873623), (0.1, 0.4689955935892812), (0.9, 0.46899559358928117), (0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0)] 

